# Query between distances in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, pfquery, geopoints

I would like to search places between two given distances, using GeoPoints. Using the currently api, I think I could make something like this pseudo algorithm:

query.whereWithinKilometers("directions", GlobalData.ownerGeoPoint, MAXIMUM distance);

MINUS

query.whereWithinKilometers("directions", GlobalData.ownerGeoPoint, MINIMUM distance);

How can I translate to real code?

Comment: It sounds like you want to find things in a doughnut shaped region.  Is that right?

Comment: That is correct, danh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do it with a parse query.

```
// Do not want locations further than maxDistance
ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyData");
query.whereWithinKilometers("location", userGeoPoint, maxDistance);

// Do not want locations closer than minDistance
ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyData");
innerQuery.whereWithinKilometers("location", userGeoPoint, minDistance);
query.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", innerQuery);
```

Comment: Can you please help me for how to calculate this "maxDistance" for a visible region on map.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you'll have to pull in everything within the maximum distance from Parse to your app, then inside your app filter out anything that is closer than the minimum.

Thankfully Parse includes some distance measuring as part of PFGeoPoint. Check out the three methods [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html).

1. distanceInRadiansTo:
2. distanceInMilesTo:
3. distanceInKilometersTo:

So your **pseudocode** is:

```
(After you get back everything within the outer radius)

Make a new array (var) called finalList
For i = 0; i < objects.count; i++ {
   var gp: PFGeoPoint = objects[i]
   if gp.distanceInMilesTo:originalGeoPoint >= minimumRadiusInMiles {
      finalList.push(gp)
   }
}
```